# sorting the List not working as expected using comparator

Tags: java, collections

When `List<Person>` is returned, i want to sort the List in descending order based on the time mentioned in ActiveStatus.

I tried the below logic

```
class Business{

  List<Person> getActivePersonListInDesc(){
  
   ....
   List<Person> personList = ..;
   Collections.sort(personList, Comparator.reverseOrder()); //not working as expected
   return personList;
   }
```

Person class:

```
class Person{
String personName;
List<ActiveStatus> status;
}
```

ActiveStatus class:

```
class ActiveStatus{
LocalDateTime time;
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? How do you expect the comparator to know what the order is?

Comment: ok , it is not sorting in descending order based on time mentioned in ActiveStatus. Tried using stream() to get the time from ActiveStatus

Comment: Doesn't make sense somehow, because your `Person` class contains a list of `ActiveStatus` objects. Which `ActiveStatus` is decisive for the sorting? The first in the list, the last, the one with the newest date or the one with the oldest date? or completely different?

Comment: Well, the comparator you've used doesn't even use active status or time. You'd need to first get relevant active status (latest time?, first element?) and it's time property for the comparison.

Comment: totally agree with comments. i was trying and will try to edit the question above . I was looking to sort list in descending order by the time property mentioned in Active status class.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each user has at least one element in `status`, that list is already sorted with the newest element being last, and you want to sort by that, you could use something like this:

```
Collections.sort(personList, 
  Comparator.comparing(person -> person.status.get(person.status.size() - 1).time)
            .reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort items based on a field within your object, you need to specify that it needs to sort on that field.

You could solve this by implementing the Comparable interface on your Person object

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        //Compare logic for the dates
    }
}
```